# Dynamic hidden fields values where model name is stored in database

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a requirement in angular js application where I need to dynamically create hidden variables. Name and value attribute for these hidden fields will be from database. But rather than storing actual value of hidden field in database name of model is stored in a database.

I have written a test function as follows. TempVars will be from database but for time being I have hard coded few values.

```
$rootScope.populate = function () {
    $rootScope.models = {
        MyModel: {}    
    };
    $rootScope.models.MyModel.Client = [];
    $rootScope.models.MyModel.Client.FirstName = 'FName';
    $rootScope.models.MyModel.Client.LastName = 'LName';
    $rootScope.TempVars = [
        {"key":"var-FirstName","value":"{{models.MyModel.Client.FirstName}}"},
        { "key": "var-LastName", "value": "{{models.MyModel.Client.LastName}}" },
    ]
};
```

Following is my HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" ng-repeat="obj in TempVars" name="{{obj.key}}" value="{{obj.value}}" />
<input type="text" ng-repeat="obj in TempVars" name="{{obj.key}}" value="{{obj.value}}" />
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="{{models.MyModel.Client.FirstName}}" />
```

I am expecting that hidden filed value should have FName and LName in it. But rather it contains `{{models.MyModel.Client.FirstName}}` and `{{models.MyModel.Client.LastName}}` in it. Whereas variable name with name test has FName value stored in it.

Is is possible to achieve this in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way in angularjs but you will be able to do that through a custom directive and using NGModelController to $format and $parse the data.
Here are some links where you can get the idea about that :

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-ngmodel-in-custom-directives
http://radify.io/blog/understanding-ngmodelcontroller-by-example-part-1/